# How to remove padding in sherlock tab view

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, customization

Is it possible to decrease/remove the padding left and right in a tab?
And how can i accomplish this? I've tried a lot but can't figure out how to do this.
I use the sherlock actionbar with tab navigation.

Comment: i've override the style of @style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView, and set the padding. set different 9 patch backgrounds, set divider settings, and some other stuff.. I just need to know where this default space is coming from..

Answer (score 2):

I finnaly found it

this can be done by setting the padding and minWidth on the TabView 
and the backgroundStacked of the Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse.

```
    <style name="GPA_Sherlock_theme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">        
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item> 
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item> 
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
</style>

 <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
     <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>        
     <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>     
     <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item> 
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"> 
     <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item> 
     <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 items for actionBarStyle and android:actionBarStyle? I am developing for API 8+ and the android one gives me errors. Will this be a problem if I don't include that one for newer phones? I tried the above without the android one and the padding on each tab still exists. I have my the styles in my base theme, which is added in my application manifest.

Comment: for devices with android 4.0 or higher you need to set android:actionBarStyle, and other android versions just actionBarStyle. Normally you would separate them (without android: in the values folder and with android: in the values-v14 folder)